# How to construct an XPath to extract the url www.fastreact.co.uk from the parent ul tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Hi I want to navigate to this exact vendor url using selenium `<li>www.fastreact.co.uk</li>`.  But I'm stuck at this part.

```
vendor_url = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="check-list"]')
#vendor_url = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="check-list"][3]')
```

**How do I navigate to that exact UL?**  From what I can see in the source code there are four occurrences where a UL contains the `class="check-list ... "`.
Also once I manage to navigate to that node **how do I output that selenium web element into human text?**

https://www.capterra.com/p/14890/Fastreact/

```
<h2 class="epsilon"><i class="ss-buildings  icon-lead  zeta"></i>VendorDetails</h2>
<ul class="check-list" >
    <li>Fast React Systems</li>
    <li>www.fastreact.co.uk</li>
    <li>Founded 1999</li>
    <li>United Kingdom</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try this: *//ul[@class="check-list"]/li[2]/text()*

Comment: @Gabrielius Thanks for the tip.  So I have four of these `<ul class="check-list ...` in the webpage.  How do I select the 3rd UL from these four UL:s?
https://www.capterra.com/p/14890/Fastreact/

Comment: Try `//ul[@class="check-list"][3]/li[2]/text()`.

Comment: I thought you were trying to select third **li** element? Www.fastreact.co.uk? In either case you should use indexer **[3]** for **ul** like you did in the comment you posted. What was the problem you had with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you are wanting:

> NOTE: This was tested using Chrome build 67 with chromedriver 2.40

```
driver.get('https://www.capterra.com/p/14890/Fastreact/')

# this will go directly to the check-list item you are wanting
vendor_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="check-list"][2]')
print(vendor_details.text)

# this will go directly to the link you are wanting
vendor_link= driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="check-list"][2]/li[2]')
print(vendor_link.text)
```

The ***print*** statements will display the text values of the elements in your console.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question to extract the *Vendor URL* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.capterra.com/p/14890/Fastreact/")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='epsilon' and contains(.,'Vendor Details')]//following::ul[1]//following-sibling::li[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  www.fastreact.co.uk
  ```

Comment: Why do you want OP to make all those imports and implement ExplicitWait to extract **static** data?

Comment: @Andersson Good question, Long story cut short, it's nothing related to **static data** as such. It's all about _new page_ where you are unsure when the _Web Client_ achieves  `'document.readyState' equal to "complete"`. Hence you must always induce a _waiter_. Let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: To get required data you don't even need to wait for `readyState == "complete"`. State `"interactive"` is more then enough, so I'm not sure about that *"...must always induce a waiter..."*

Comment: @Andersson Yeap, perhaps you are correct on this individual instance/question. But my answer is pretty generic following the _best practices_. Of-coarse all the browsers doesn't wait for `readyState == "complete"` barring a few. After all, even achieving `readyState == "complete"` (let's keep off `"interactive"`) may not suffice enough for a user to interact with the prevailing _DOM Tree_. hence we need the _waiter_.